# EllipticCurve, sagemath

Tags: sage, elliptic-curve

I have an elliptic curve defined by 
y^2 = x^3 + 1062282974404935987005872930817*x + 1204388198013706813607478558721 over Finite Field of size 2017313518945563799802055961909.

And I want to get a point on this curve of order 3569809307570934983774171.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can see that the order of **E**, is 2017313518945565643070719128784. The main stage is that you find the generator(s) of E, and with SageMath they are:

*H_1* = (651721743085147348480059087840, 277924022187240437411690075386)

and

*H_2* = (364767631279436218861124076682, 0)

But you can see that the order of *H_1* is 1008656759472782821535359564392, so

**G = 565104 * H_1**

**G = (1144674520220442511918931779419, 850803345221750997044804585048)**

is the desired point on **E**.